# get Woocommerce attribute term thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have managed to figure out how to fetch attribute term names the code that works is this (i realize global $product isnt doing anything right now below):

```
global $product;

$terms = get_terms("pa_melamine");

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  echo "<option>" . $term->name . "</option>";
}
```

And when i dump $terms i get this:

```
  public 'term_id' => string '69' (length=2)
  public 'name' => string 'Bistro' (length=6)
  public 'slug' => string 'bistro' (length=6)
  public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '69' (length=2)
  public 'taxonomy' => string 'pa_melamine' (length=11)
  public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'count' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'meta_id' => string '85' (length=2)
  public 'woocommerce_term_id' => string '69' (length=2)
  public 'meta_key' => string 'order_pa_melamine' (length=17)
  public 'meta_value' => string '0' (length=1)
```

I am trying to get the thumbnail images i have attached to attribute terms, they are swatches. I have no idea how i can fetch the thumbnail attachment.

If anyone needs more info please let me know.

Comment: How are you adding thumbnails to the attribute terms? That isn't part of WooCommerce core. Do you mean the thumbnails that are attached to each variation?

Comment: Ah its being added in the META. its part of a plugin called Woocommerce Visual Attributes.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ae0j7frg2kql3g5/ql-main.php?dl=0 the front-end parts of the plugin can be found in the above php file

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts in your question?

Comment: Not even sure what i relevant in that code, i am not sure what i need to be pulling. They way i understand is the code i linked in dropbox inserts the thumbnail into the meta of woocommerce attributes? But i am not sure what i relevant there

Comment: The meta of the variation? Or the meta of the term? If you can get more specific, I can try to help. I don't have time to read through their entire plugin right now. Is there no documentation? Have you contacted the author/support?

Comment: Ah sorry, ye the meta of the term. I am actually trying to still figure it out now. I havent tried contacting the author, this needed to be done yesterday, and my php is so poor, i am just learning here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about that plugin. That's why I needed you to narrow it down a bit. If the plugin has any docu, I'd start there.